# What is the convenient way of fetching array from DB to extract it then to vars in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm newbie learning PHP.

I have a MySQL table looking like this:

[image]

Working on fetching data from it using PDO.

**My task?**

I need to make arithmetic calculations between elements of this array. I.e.:

`$sel_1_1 + $day`, where `$sel_1_1` is the first element of column select1

`$sel_1_2 + $day`, where `$sel_1_2` is the second element of column select1

`$sel_2_1 + $day`, where `$sel_1_2` is the first element of column select2

`$sel_2_2 + $day`, where `$sel_1_2` is the second element of column select2

**How I try to solve it**

I need to fetch data from 4 columns (day, select1, select2, select3) in the form of array and to extract elements of these arrays into separate variables.

This is how I do:

```
$loged = 'test';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT select1, select2, select3, day 
                       FROM day_table 
                       WHERE login=?");
$stmt->execute([$loged]);
$res = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($res as $key=>$row) {
   $sel1 = $row['select1'];
   $sel2 = $row['select2'];
   $sel3 = $row['select3'];
   $day_from_db = $row['day'];
}

echo $sel1;  //  This fetches only the last element of "Select1" array.

echo $day_from_db; // Also fetches only the last element of "Day" array

echo "<pre>".print_r($res, true)."</pre>";
```

Output looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [select1] => 2 
        [select2] => 2 
        [select3] => 2 
        [birthday] => 2018-06-24 ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [select1] => 16 
        [select2] => 10 
        [select3] => 7 
        [birthday] => 2018-07-27 ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [select1] => 2 
        [select2] => 2 
        [select3] => 2 
        [birthday] => 2018-07-29 ) 
)
```

Then I try to extract my big array usung PHP extract:

```
$e = extract($res);
echo $e;
```

Returns `0`.

And if I try doing in another manner like this:

```
// Fetch column day:
$sql = "SELECT day FROM day_table WHERE login=?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$loged]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

$day0 = $result[0];
$day1 = $result[1];
$day2 = $result[2];
echo $day0."<br>";
echo $day1."<br>";
echo $day2."<br>";

// Fetch column select1:
$sql = "SELECT select1 FROM day_table WHERE login=?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$loged]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

$select0 = $result[0];
$select1 = $result[1];
$select2 = $result[2];
echo $select0."<br>";
echo $select1."<br>";
echo $select2."<br>";
```

Returns desired values, but this is not good approach because:

1. If there are lots of elements in columns this becomes senselessly,
2. This is bad, non optimal code.

Can you please help me solving my issue with good, appropriate method?

Comment: `$sel1[] = $row['select1'];` could fetch all values to your array because in the first way you overwrite the array many times and only have the last value... Note that in your case `$sel1` is not an array, its a variable. But it is not a good way of storing data...

Comment: You don't want variable variables! You want an array of arrays! Which you already have in `$res`. Just use that.

Comment: + for very nice description of your problem

Comment: @deceze, sorry, couldn't catch how exact can I use it?

Comment: Instead of first creating and then using `$needless_extra_variable_1_5`, you use `$my_array[1][5]` …

Comment: `$res[0]['select1']`, `$res[1]['select1']` etc. You don't need to assign it to other variables. You just need to loop through that array and do whatever you need to do (which I'm not entire sure what that is).

Comment: @deceze, I need to make calculations between elements of my 4 arrays, fetched from db. Consider the calendar with reminder: I need to add or substract elements of select1, select and select3 to/from elements of day column. And I need to do it in linear way: `$res[0]['select1'] + $res[0]['day'], $res[1]['select1'] + $res[1]['day']`etc. I'm confused because if I have lots of elements in columns I can't do it manually, that;s why I need a loop as you say and as I understood. Сould you please clarify to me what loop and how should I use?